# how to add port number to working copy url in svn on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, svn, port

hi here i have installed svn on my ubuntu server successfully changed its port number to 1234.problem is here when i try to commit my files it says

```
svn: E000111: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E000111: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://144.**.**.***/svn/ihubrep'
svn: E000111: Error running context: Connection refused
```

it is because svn is  trying to connect to my old url which is using defult port number instead of connecting to new one, can any one please help me how to add that port number to svn url.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and succeeded.

`svn switch --relocate` is deprecated in version 1.7 of subversion. Use the svn command relocate.

`svn help` relocate

for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Since it seems to be standard syntax just write http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port/.../.

EDIT:
Example with your URL:
Your URL with your example would look like this if you wanted to access it on port 1234:

```
http://144.**.**.***:1234/svn/ihubrep
```

EDIT2:
I missunderstood the question.

Comment: please give me a proper ans.u can still comment on my que insted of answering.

Comment: I missunderstood your question, sorry.